# JQuery object of an array to string

Tags: jquery, arrays, arrayobject

I retrieved an object of array from my code behind(PHP) into my JQuery and get:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [MFID] => 1
            [MFName] => Customer ID
            [FTID] => 1
            [DTID] => 1
            [MFKey] => 0
            [MFWSKey] => 
            [MFWSName] => 
            [MFRequired] => 1
            [MFDefaultValue] => 
            [MFMin] => 0
            [MFMax] => 0
            [MFDueDate] => 0
            [MFToBePaid] => 0
            [MFMaxLength] => 50
            [MFOrderNo] => 1
            [MFStatus] => 1
        )

)
```

I want to get the MFName from that array into a certain input object, lets say

```
$("#fname").val(data[0]['MFName']);
```

But that does not work.

Usually I do it in Php before returning it to the client,

```
    $val = $array[0]->MFname;
```

How can I do it in JQuery?

Comment: Are you getting the data in JSON or actually this format? Because this format cannot be read by jQuery/javascript

Comment: Hm.. I am not sure, I just get the data from Codebehind and return it it using
    jConfirm("Edit this field?","Confirm",function(r){
           if(r)
               {
                   $.post("<?php echo site_url('merchantfield/merchantfield_process'); ?>",
                    {
                        action  : 'VIEW_ONE',
                        id      : id
       
                    },function(data){
                        alert(data);

i get the result into the data, but thats not what I need.

Comment: I'd recommend firing up Firebug in Firefox or Chrome's javascript debugger and seeing what's coming across the wire.

Comment: What does `console.log(data);` give you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

// return json encoded array in php side

```
var arr = JSON.parse(yourArray);
alert(arr[0].MFname);
```

Hope you will find using this

Comment: I am getting an error:

SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character
[Break On This Error]  

var arr =  JSON.parse(data);

Comment: (http://www.JSON.org/json2.js)
download json2.js you will get the JSON.parse() function

Comment: Thank you for the response, decided to go the hard way instead:

`echo ($fields[0]->MFID."|".$fields[0]->MFName."|".$fields[0]->FTID."|".$fields[0]->DTID."|".$fields[0]->MFKey."|".$fields[0]->MFRequired."|".$fields[0]->MFDefaultValue."|".$fields[0]->MFMin."|".$fields[0]->MFMax."|".$fields[0]->MFDueDate."|".$fields[0]->MFToBePaid."|".$fields[0]->MFMaxLength."|".$fields[0]->MFOrderNo."|".$fields[0]->MFStatus);

from PhP, then gonna use 
    `var _ct = _data.split("|");
                    
                    $("#fname").html( _ct[1]);

thank you